# How to convert nested function call tree to state machine?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parsing, state-machine, automata

Say you have this sort of system:

```js
const input = [0, [1, 2, [3, 4, [8, 9], 6, 7], 4], [5, 6, 7], 3, 4, [8, 9], 6, 7, [1], 9]
const output = parse(input)
console.log(output.join('-'))

function parse(input) {
  const output = []
  iterate(input, value => {
    check(() => isArray(value),
      () => { // yes array
        const children = parse(value)
        output.push(...children)
      },
      () => { // not array
        check(() => isEven(value), () => {
          output.push(value)
        })
      })
  })
  return output
}

function isArray(value) {
  return Array.isArray(value)
}

function isEven(value) {
  return value % 2 == 0
}

function check(condition, success, failure) {
  if (condition()) success()
  else if (failure) failure()
}

function iterate(array, block) {
  array.forEach(block)
}
```

Essentially this is like a tree grammar:

```
parse =
  iterate input, value =>
    check isArray(value)
      call parse(value)
    check isNumber(value)
      check isEven(value)
        push(value)
```

You can imagine this as JSON:

```
{
  type: 'function',
  name: 'parse',
  children: [
    {
      type: 'iterate',
      children: [
        {
          type: 'check',
          checker: 'isArray',
          children: [
            {
              type: 'call',
              function: 'parse'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          type: 'check',
          checker: 'isNumber',
          children: [
            {
              type: 'check',
              checker: 'isEven',
              children: [
                {
                  type: 'push',
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> *Basically my real problem is I have something like this JSON in a custom programming language, and I want to convert it into a state
> machine rather than the nested/recursive function calls like we
> started with in this post.*

So my question is, **how can you rewrite the recursive function system from the beginning of this post, such that it uses a state machine instead?**

> You don't have to go all the way and make the state machine from the
> JSON (which in this example is incomplete, as I don't have a good
> example to simplify from).

Instead, just if you could show how to rewrite this recursive or nested function system from the beginning of this post as  a state machine, that would be all.

What I am imagining is something like this:

```
let transitions = [
  function1,
  function2,
  ...
]

let transition = transitions[0] // the start function in theory
let currentInput = input
let someStack = []
while (transition) {
  [currentInput, transition] = transition(someStack, currentInput)
}
```

But I quickly get lost on how I would keep track of the position we are at in the input, as well as how to handle things like iteration (as in the `iterator`), or "if statements" (as in the `check`).

```
function iterate(input) {
  // you can't do the recursive call here,
  // as the original while loop should handle this.
  // but, we should return some reference to the current input,
  // as well as the next transition.
}
```

If a language must be chosen then doing this in JavaScript would be simplest. But it can even be done in pseudocode to show generally how it's done.

Comment: The question is not clear. The word "parsing" implies that the input is a string and you read character by character. That's not the case in your example where `input` is an already parsed JS value. Please clarify.

Comment: Also what's wrong with the recursive approach?

Comment: @Olivier by parsing I mean taking some input and converting it into output. My example uses a nested array system (a tree), which is close to my input which I will be "parsing". But if it is easier you can imagine a string instead, either way works for me. There is no inherent problem with the recursive approach necessarily, I just want to know how to do this like a transition machine somehow. For my learnings.

Comment: Defunctionalization _might be_ relevant for your problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wppzFzzD4b8

Comment: Are you just doing a tree rewriting? your input and out both looks like trees.
Something like a visitor pattern + stack of strategy pattern may work for that. Should I expand on this?

Comment: Hi, your bounty is expiring soon, you should engage with comments if you want a good answer. Is the set of 'isEven, isNumber isArray' a finite set?
It is only 'isArray' that is a 'composite'?

Comment: This is a good. https://aclanthology.org/W89-0229.pdf

Comment: @MarcoServetto sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure what you mean by finite set, `isArray` is a function that returns if it is an array, while `isNumber` returns true if a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said, you can not use a state machine, but if I understand your example, you do not need one.
You want a way to construct predicates from data;
those predicates will work on a complex irregular data structure.

- Some of those predicates will have side effects.
- Some of those predicates will propagate the operation on sub parts of the data.
- I'm assuming you have a finite way to express your predicates, so you can compose a finite set of predicates to obtain your desired ones.

If Java streams had a 'recursive' flatMap, that would be enough.

I'm a Java expert so I will write an attempt in Java.
The main idea is to have an Op functional interface that maps an Object into a list of objects.

Then you just compute a fix-point.

```
interface Op{ List<Object> of(Object t); }
class A{
  Op push(List<Object> res){
    return o->{res.add(o);return List.of();};
    }  
  Op isArray(){
    return t->{
      if (!(t instanceof Object[] os)){ return List.of(); }
      return List.of(os);
      };
    }
  Op isNumber(Op more){
    return t->{
      if (!(t instanceof Integer i)){ return List.of(); }
      return more.of(i);
      };
    }
  Op isEven(Op more){
    return t->{
      if (!(t instanceof Integer i) || i%2==1){ return List.of(); }
      return more.of(i);
      };
    }
  void engine1(List<Op> query,Object input){//not recursive
    List<Object>edge=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object>nextEdge=new ArrayList<>();
    edge.add(input);
    while(!edge.isEmpty()){
      for(var e:edge){
        for(var f:query){
          nextEdge.addAll(f.of(e));
          }
        }
      edge=nextEdge;
      nextEdge=new ArrayList<>();
      }
    }
  void example1() {
    List<Object> res=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Op> query=List.of(isArray(),isEven(push(res)));
    Object input= new Object[]{1,2,new Object[]{3,4},5,6};
    engine1(query,input);
    System.out.println(res);
    }
  public static void main(String[]arg) {
    new A().example1();//this would print 2,6,4
    }
  }
```

It is unclear from your question if  this order is acceptable for you.
That is, the visit side effects are Breadth First
If not, I think I can get the Deapth First order instead, but it will have to be in 12 hours or so, since it is now getting late in my timezone.

Comment: This is a good start, I will have to take some time to study this as I am not a Java expert, but it looks like it's in the right direction I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. A [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) cannot recognise/parse a [language with a recursive grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) but only a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). You would need a [stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton).

Comment: Can you show how to do that? That's what I was looking for and I don't want to ask the same question again with a different title. Had I asked for a pushdown automata, one would have said that you can't build output with an automaton (which only returns true/false).